# Migrate and merge SpamAssassin

Tags: spamassassin

I have two separate SpamAssassin configurations that I need to merge into one.

Since both of them have seen gzillion mails I'd feel stupid to dismiss one of them. Is it possible to merge their spam/ham databases?

Comment: I think we need more detail here about what you mean when you say merge. Are you wanting to merge the spam/ham databases?  Merging the actual configuration should just mean that you need to review the 2 configurations and come up with a new one.

Comment: Yes, I'll clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found how to migrate spam/ham database

http://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.2.x/doc/sa-learn.html#migration

No info yet on how to merge them...

Comment: you may consider not accepting this answer so that your question will be listed on "unanswered"